# Network interface in KAA

Tags: kaa

Well,I am trying to install KAA single node on my ubuntu 14.04. I followed the steps in the kaa website. The only step I skipped was the Network interface. Because I don't know what it means. I don't know how to specify a hostname or an IP address. Then,when I start kaa and grep errors,they are

```
HHH000319: Could not get database metadata
HHH000299: Could not complete schema update
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'sqladmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
Context initialization failed
Kaa Node Server will be stopped.
```

I've been working on it for several weeks, what should I do?

Comment: I hope you are following the instructions [here](https://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/) to set up kaa v 0.10.0. You should provide the public interface so that the Kaa endpoints can communicate to the server. To get your public IP address type `ifconfig` on terminal. Let's say it is `192.168.200.10` then you have to update entry `transport_public_interface=192.168.200.10` in `kaa-node.properties`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I followed your steps but there are still many errors when I use grep error. It said that:                                                                      [Could not get database metadata
Could not connect: Access denied for user 'sqladmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
Failed to connect to Zookeeper within 5 minutes. Kaa Node Server will be stopped.]
However, I checked that my zookeeper and mongDB is running. And when I open the url http://YOUR_SERVER_HOST:8080/kaaAdmin, it just said that it can't connect to the server. What should I do ?

Comment: Whats the result of `sudo /usr/share/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh status` ?

Comment: Well,it shows that:JMX enabled by default Using config: /etc/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg Mode:standalone. I don't understand what they means..

Comment: and `sudo service zookeperd status` ? If it's unable to find the service do `sudo apt-get install zookeeperd`. Delete all the log files and try to start kaa.